# Get latest account balance per user on specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have the following query in SQL to determine the balance of user accounts on a specific date (ex: end year 2019-12-31)

The following query gives me all transactions before that date, and I then need to get the `BALANCE_REAL` value for each `USERID` before 2019-12-31, when his latest action occurred

My current query goes like this:

```
 SELECT
    USERID,
    a.PartyID,
    DATETIME,
    BALANCE_REAL 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ACCOUNT_ID + 88888 AS PartyID,
        DATETIME,
        BALANCE_REAL 
    FROM
        admin_all.ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL 
    WHERE
        DATETIME < '2020-01-01'  
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT PARTYID, USERID FROM external_mpt.USER_CONF ) b ON a.PartyID= b.PARTYID
```

It gives this output:

```
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| USERID | PartyID | DATETIME                | BALANCE_REAL            |
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Nasa   | 1819895 | 2019-12-30 00:00:04.503 | 1140.000000000000000000 |
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Mesha  | 1819753 | 2019-12-30 00:00:06.256 | 0.000000000000000000    |
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Mesha  | 1819753 | 2019-12-30 00:00:18.406 | 1400.000000000000000000 |
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Nasa   | 1819895 | 2019-12-30 00:00:34.683 | 1638.000000000000000000 |
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| JO76   | 1819728 | 2019-12-30 00:00:45.046 | 1175.000000000000000000 |
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Mesha  | 1819753 | 2019-12-30 00:00:58.896 | 1625.000000000000000000 |
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Nasa   | 1819895 | 2019-12-30 00:01:01.876 | 1016.000000000000000000 |
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Nasa   | 1819895 | 2019-12-30 00:01:26.456 | 1346.000000000000000000 |
+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

So my last balance per user result should show 1346 for NASA at 2019-12-30 00:01:26.456 , 1625 for Mesha at 2019-12-30 00:00:58.896  and 1175 for JO76 at 2019-12-30 00:00:45.046

How can I modify my query to reach this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT USERID, PartyID, DATETIME, BALANCE_REAL 
FROM (SELECT u.USERID,
             (a.ACCOUNT_ID + 88888) AS PartyID, a.DATETIME, a.BALANCE_REAL,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.USERID ORDER BY a.DATETIME DESC) as seqnum
      FROM admin_all.ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL JOIN
           external_mpt.USER_CONF u
           ON (a.ACCOUNT_ID + 88888) = u.PARTYID 
      WHERE DATETIME < '2020-01-01'  
    ) a
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: it throws an error "[SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'. (156)"

Comment: fine, it was a parenthesis missing